# Density in $\ell^{2}$

Tags: functional-analysis

How can i prove that $c_{00}$ is dense in $(\ell^{2}, \| \cdot \|_{\ell^{2}})$?

Where with $c_{00}$ i mean

\begin{equation}
c_{00}=\{ x\in\ell^2 \, | \,\exists\overline{n}\in\mathbb{N}, \forall n>\overline{n} \, x(n)=0\}.
\end{equation}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\epsilon>0$ be given, choose $x\in\ell^2$. We know that $\sum_{i\in\mathbb{N}}|x_i|^2<\infty$, so there exists an $N$ such that $\sum_{i=N}^\infty |x_i|^2<\epsilon$. Can you know construct a sequence $y\in c_{00}$ such that $\|x-y\|_{\ell^2}<\epsilon$? How about

$$
y_n=\begin{cases} x_n\quad\,n\leq N\\
0\quad\,else
\end{cases}
$$

Comment: Ok, now i got it! i was missing the part of taking a sequence $y_{n}$ that converges to $x$ in the $\| \cdot \|_{\ell^{2}}$ norm. Observing the convergence is enough to conclude about the density, right?

Comment: A question: the above argument is enough to conclude that the space $(c_{00}, \| \cdot \|_{\ell^{2})$ is not a complete space?

Comment: I don't think this argument shows that the space is complete. It only shows denseness.

Comment: Well, we know that $\ell^2\setminus c_{00}$ is not empty, so take $x \in \ell^2\setminus c_{00}$. By denseness there is a sequence $(x_n)_{n \in \Bbb{N}}$ that converges to $x$ in the $\ell^2$-norm. As convergent sequences are always Cauchy (whenever Cauchy makes sense), we have found a Cauchy sequence in $c_{00}$ that does not converge in $c_{00}$